# Don't show 's3.amazon.com' when posting images to LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am posting images to LinkedIn through the public api with my app that pulls the images from our S3 bucket.  When the update appears on LinkedIn it shows 's3.amazon.com' next to the image.  Is there any way that I can keep this from happening?

Ruby Code from app:

```
 def post(message_body, attachment, post)
        options = { :visibility => { :code => 'anyone' } }
        if attachment.present?
          options.merge!(:content => { :title         => 'titles',
                                       :description   => 'descriptions',
                                       :submitted_url => 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/...'
                                     }, :comment => message_body)
        else
           options.merge!(:comment => message_body)
        end
        response = client.add_share(options)
        post.posted!
        JSON.parse(response.body)['updateUrl']
      rescue LinkedIn::Errors::UnauthorizedError => e
        raise SocialProfile::UnauthorizedError, e.message
      rescue LinkedIn::Errors::AccessDeniedError => e
        raise SocialProfile::UnauthorizedError, e.message
      ## Heading ##end
```